# Can I create composite/layered SvgIcons in material-ui?

Tags: svg, material-ui

I would like to make custom SVG Icons by layering two or more existing material-ui icons together.  For example, add a "+" icon layered over the top of another icon to indicate "Add ".

For example, if I want to make something similar to the AddAPhoto icon, but I'm adding a store, I would like to layer the "Add" icon on top of the "Storefront" icon.

I can't seem to find any documentation or examples of this, but I swear I've seen it done in the past.  (It may have been Font Awesome)

**Edit:**

After playing around with things for a while I'm getting close.  This gives me what I'm after, except the "Add" icon needs to have an opaque background to cover up what's under it.

```
import SvgIcon from "@material-ui/core/SvgIcon";
import StorefrontIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Storefront";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";

<SvgIcon color="action" style={{height: 200, width: 200}}>
   <AddIcon color="secondary" viewBox="0 0 50 50" />
   <StorefrontIcon/>
</SvgIcon>
```

Comment: If the 2 svg elements have the same viewBox you can put the content of both elements in  the same svg element keeping in mind that the last added element apears on top of the previous ones . Pleae edit your question and add the 2 icons you want to merge so that we can help you.